# Microsoft Cognitive Services Speech SDK JavaScript and C# Quickstart samples both giving error while enrolling profile

Tags: speech-recognition, azure-cognitive-services, speaker-diarization

We are using Microsoft Cognitive Services Speech SDK JavaScript and C# Quick start samples and I am getting error while enrollment of user profile.

**"Activation Phrase is not matched"**

Are any bug in SDK ? I am passing all parameters but it is not working in both languages.

Refer below screenshot.
[image]

I tried Microsoft Sample use cases  and passing required parameters.

Comment: @Upendra Check this [MS DOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/azure/ai-services/speech-service/get-started-speaker-recognition?tabs=script&pivots=programming-language-csharp) for enrollment of a profile ID.

Comment: @Sampath I am using below Github sample  https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-speech-sdk/tree/master/quickstart/javascript/browser/speaker-recognition/identification

Comment: @DasariKamali I followed github documents and github samples , i changed only key and region but it is giving error.  May I know, what wrong I am doing?

Comment: @DasariKamali I am taking about speaker-recognition/identification https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-speech-sdk/tree/master/quickstart/javascript/browser/speaker-recognition/identification     and here it is returning profileId but it is not enrolling voice profile